# Write git commit message before 'git commit'

Tags: git

I'm learning Git coming from Perforce.

As far as I can tell you must write the commit message in the same step as when you commit.  Or am I missing how I might write the message earlier and have it hang around until I'm ready to commit.

I really liked the workflow in perforce where you can edit the changelist description at any time, and then checkin when you're ready.  Personally, I like to open the description many times and document as I code, or as I think of noteworthy things to point out.

Possible with Git?

Comment: Good question. As far as I can tell from the git-commit man page you cannot do this directly (you can use `-F` and store the commit message outside git), but since git allows you to build up a commit incrementally, you'd expect to be able to do that with the commit message too.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Have a look at the `-t <file>` flag with `git commit`

This lets you specify a file to use as the basis for the commit message. The editor is still invoked but at least you can use a commit message which you create in advance.

**Alternatively**, there is another workflow that you can use with git that might better suit your way of working:

With git you can work on a separate branch from the main line and make lots of small commits with their own messages. Although each of these commits by themselves may not solve the problem that you are working on, they do provide a way of saving the intermediate states of your work with the same sort of messages that you may have been updating in your commit message file.

Once you are ready to commit the sum of your work, you can use the `rebase` command and `squash` these commits together. Your editor will then be invoked with the all the individual messages that you used for the smaller commits which you can then edit together into a single message.

This is a lot easier than it sounds here, and is IMHO a more git-like approach.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since the -t is most like what I was looking for.  Interesting to know about the other workflows though, thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty new to git and just saw this. So what I understood is with `rebase`/`squash` I can bring down all my small commits in a branch to one commit? When doing pull requests, what's the 'git way'? Squash all commits into one and pull request my branch, or keep all commits for the upstream maintainer to see? Also, if my pull request has many commits, and it gets merged, does the final upstream repo show all these commits, or just one that says 'Merged from pull request'?

Comment: The problem with the "more git-like approach" is that each commit message is still written after the code that was written for it — the fact that the changes are small ameliorates the problem but does not eliminate it. The thing that the OP wants (and Perforce encourages, at least for a few people) is to write the changelist description before writing a single line of code. It puts you in a different state of mind, which helps sometimes.

Comment: Please add the `-F` option, which commits without opening the editor, from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41402878/905686).

Comment: Great point about the `git rebase && git squash` workflow! Additionally, there's absolutely no reason that these two workflows can't be used together. Keeping a commit message draft is extremely useful for tracking todo lists & other checklists to keep you from forgetting anything when writing your smaller, incremental commits. That way, your squashed commit message can encompass all of your progress.

Comment: I like the `rebase` approach. I can just add a title at the top and leave everything else be if I `s` everything.

Answer (score 9):

As long as you haven't `push` your commit to others, you can do a `git commit --amend`.  This will allow you to modify your commit, as well as your commit message.

I found this really help with the 'commit early and often', without get overwhelm by the number of trivial commits.

Comment: hmm, still understanding the git way of doing things, but this seems to subvert the point of commiting checkpoints, where the last commit is really "commit in progress".

Comment: It has the flexibility of doing so.  You don't need to use it, but it's there if you need it.

Comment: @AK do it on a private branch and nobody has to know that you are rewriting HEAD

Answer (score 7):

You could use these aliases:

```
git config --global alias.prepare '!${EDITOR:-vi} $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/.template'
git config --global alias.commitp '!git commit -F $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/.template'
```

Usage:

```
git prepare
EDITOR=nano git prepare # heeds standard EDITOR variable
git commitp
```

This keeps your commit message in `.git/.template`.

But rather than this, you should really just use a workflow where you commit atomic and small changes often, and use feature branches when necessary to group those changes. If you merge with `git merge --no-ff $branch`, you can use `git log --first-parent` later to ignore the branches.

Comment: IMO this is a great answer. The last paragraph doesn't need to disparage it.

Comment: Useful indeed.  And to edit the message upon commit as well, add -e before -F (which seems to better match the op's Perforce expectations; and mine).

Comment: Renaming .template to GITGUI_MSG works with git gui, as @johnny commented for another answer.

Comment: +1 for the innovative approach! Keep in mind that this approach doesn't play nicely with `git stash` and `git checkout`, since you can very easily end up overwriting draft messages if you are working on multiple branches simultaneously. I'm sure that `git hash-object` and `git write-tree` could be used to make this more friendly for parallel workflows.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the motivation for this question is to be able to write the description (commit message) *before* writing any code (while of course being able to modify it as the code is written). (Having used Perforce and a Perforce-like system before, I know it helps sometimes to be in that frame of mind, where you write a description of what you're going to do, before actually writing the code to do it.)

Apart from writing the message in a file and using the `-t <file>` (`--template=<file>`) or `-F <file>` (`--file=<file>`) flags to `git commit`, another approach is the following:

1. Make an empty commit with `git commit --allow-empty`. This will, just like any `git commit`, bring up an editor where you can write the message. Write it and finish the commit.
2. Make your code changes.
3. Add the files you want to add with `git add` and then `git commit --amend` (or just `git commit -a --amend` if you don't want to pick out specific files with `git add`). This will make the earlier non-empty commit now no longer empty, and you can also edit the message to more closely match what you actually did (if you prefer).

(If you're working with others, remember not to `git push` while doing this: don't amend commits you've already pushed!)

Of course the advice to keep your commits as small and atomic as possible still applies, but this way lets you write the message before writing the code. (The `git commit --amend` approach has already been suggested in another answer; I'm only additionally pointing out that you can go all the way using `git commit --allow-empty`.)

Comment: The problem with not pushing the empty commit (with the description) is that one of the reasons for writing the description first is to announce your intentions to others. One of the values of Perforce changelist descriptions is that others can read the descriptions of your work in progress. So if I see that Bob is working on the file `foo.c` I can read his description to see what he intends to do, and if it conflicts with what I intend to do, I can call Bob and we can figure out how to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `git gui` and just leave it open while you work. Write the commit message for the bugfix you're about to do, then do the actual code changes, stage it, and commit it.

Comment: `git gui` is part of the git suite, thus it's available for all platforms git is available.

Comment: Edited to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: `git gui`, at least in version 0.13 as part of git 1.7.4.msysgit.0, saves the commit message in `.git/GITGUI_MSG` between commits, so you don't even need to leave it open while you work... you could even use that file as your temp edit location - that way if you use the GUI you'll have your notes and if you commit from the command line, you just use -t .git/GITGUI_MSG...

Answer (score 2):

Write it in a file; keep it updated as you work.  Include the finalized version when actually committing.

If you're using a graphical frontend for git, then you'll have to specify which so someone can help with it specifically.  In general, you can simply paste the message.

Using git from a command line, it will open your editor with a temp file and you can read the message into it (e.g. :r filename in vim).

Or you could use your shell to read that file as the value for the -m parameter:

```
# bash example, may work elsewhere
git commit -m "$(<filename)"
```

Comment: -1: This just isn't a good answer IMHO. We all know we could write something down elsewhere beforehand - that's incredibly obvious. Clearly the poster was asking for a feature of git do to what they wanted.

Comment: @camh: Git is flexible and doesn't try to take over your entire process.  Using your favorite editor when committing *is* a feature of git.

Comment: @camh and yet in a way, that's all perforce is really doing.  Since git has the -F flag, you could keep a file for commit messages up to date and just use the -F flag.  That is to say, git has special support for it.  If you really want, you could even write a git script that edits it for you.  All it'd do is call up vi, but it's a pretty darn simple task, so...

Comment: @Roger: I understand this, but your answer does not address the question: "Possible with Git?" At they very least you could refer to `git-commit -F` which is very relevant to your answer.

Comment: @siride: It's not that simple. I'd expect a staged commit message to be stashed with the index when using git-stash for example. Other operations that affect the index should also similarly affect a staged commit message. This would not happen automatically using files outside git and `-F` with commit.

Comment: @camh: If you think you have a better answer, please, post it. I usually prefer to stick to consistent ways in which all of my tools can be used.  What's clear to you may not have been clear to the OP, who asked if they are missing something obvious.

Comment: @camh well, just add that file to your git repo to be tracked and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Built in, not as far as I know. If you're *really* desperate though, you could write it in the Terminal like `COMMIT="Fix for bug #14453"`, `COMMIT="$COMMIT and bug #4329"` then commit like `git commit -m "$COMMIT"`.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple option is to write a git commit with no changes, and amend that:

```
$ git commit --allow-empty
# create message
$ git commit --allow-empty --amend
# edit message
```

You could create an alias:

```
$ git config --global alias.draft 'commit --allow-empty'
$ git draft
# create message
$ git draft --amend
# edit message
```

This has all the benefits of git commits:

- You will get "backups" in reflog in case you make a mistake.
- You can add files to index and `--amend` them to the commit as usual.
- You can push the draft message to your feature branch.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--file <path>` argument for the `commit` command.

```
git commit --file <absolute or relative path to file>
```

And replace the <*absolute or relative path to file*> with the path to the file.

#### Example for a relative file in the directory above the repository directory:

```
git commit --file ../commit-message.txt
```

You can work on the commit message in any text editor and leave it open. Just save the file and then commit with a constant commit command. It takes the message from the text file (.txt) without opening a editor.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `-t <file>` answer, if you plan to use it every single time, is to set :
`git config commit.template <file>`.
This will implicitely use `-t` on every commit.

Answer (score -1):

To add to MatrixFrog's answer, the GitKraken GUI (https://support.gitkraken.com/working-with-commits/commits/) provides similar functionality. It allows to draft the commit message inside the GUI before/while implementing the actual changes.

In addition, it allows to set a template to structure the commit body, e.g.:

---

changes:

foo

--

new tests:

bar