# Collect commit messages from all previous commits during merge for changelog

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a main branch and a feature branch. The feature branch is several commits ahead of the main branch, and I'd like to merge the feature branch into the main branch. I don't intend to `--squash` and I don't want to `rebase` because I like preserving the history.

I like to summarize what changed in the merge's commit message because the feature branch history can get convoluted, and a good starting point for me is to copy & edit all of the commit messages from the feature branch's assorted commits *since the last merge*.

I vaguely remember reading somewhere that git can compile these messages for me, but I don't remember where I read that or how to do it.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but several Google and SO searches have failed to bring this up.

Edit: Essentially what I'm trying to do is build a changelog for everything that changed between releases.

Comment: use `git shortlog`?

Comment: Rebase will keep all the commits intact. Do you use github? With github, I create a Pull Request and merge to master. While merging, GH gives option to "squash and commit" or "keep history". Choose as required and merge.

Comment: @MohanaRao When you "squash and commit" on GitHub, don't you lose the history of the merge itself because it's not technically a merge?

Comment: True, in your case you choose the other option (Don't Squash).

Comment: I found this link,hope this helps. https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/#rebase-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I vaguely remember reading somewhere that git can compile these messages for me

Maybe through [`git rebase`, as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6934882/6309): don't go through the rebase (cancel it), but copy-paste the aggregated commit messages subjects shown during the rebase.

Otherwise, you could not those messages manually (as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4799424/6309)).

Or use a tool like [antham/chyle](https://github.com/antham/chyle) to fetch those commit messages from your history.

Comment: I think the rebase-and-cancel option must be what I was remembering. That `chyle` option is intriguing, though. I'll have to check that out.

Answer (score 1):

A

```
git log --oneline HEAD ^master
```

will create an output like this in `git rebase -i master`.

Perhaps pipe through `| cat` to remove the colored annotations.

Answer (score 0):

The `--log` [parameter for merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---logltngt) is what you are looking for:

```
  --log[=<n>], --no-log
       In addition to branch names, populate the log message with one-line
       descriptions from at most <n> actual commits that are being merged.
       See also git-fmt-merge-msg(1).
```