# Git - appending to an upcoming commit message

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way to achieve the following workflow:

1. I make a small change to my code
2. I append text describing the
   previous code change to a message that
   will be attached to my **next
   commit**
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 until ready to
   commit
4. Commit with full message text
   automatically attached (*possibly with an option to append a final text to the message*)

**EDIT:**
The message would only apply to a single commit.  This would enable you to make continuous additions to your upcoming commit message.

Currently, the best solution is to commit on the first change, and then **commit --amend** on each following change and modify the previous message.

Comment: I voted to migrate to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Was actually going to do that but thought I would get a lot of votes to migrate back here...

Comment: Doesn't git have a separate push step to get all your changes to the repository? You can do commits to your local repo at whatever granularity you want (effectively repeating your steps 1 and 2) and then do a push when you're ready (that's your step 4).

Comment: I could definitely **commit --amend** and then change the message each time. Is that a good idea?

Comment: @Jack I'm thinking more along the lines of many local commits followed by a single push.

Comment: @Jack: I'm going to say no, it's not a good idea. I'm actually curious why you want to do step 2 *at all.* Git already maintains your commit history and every commit has a reference to its parent commit. Unless you're aggregating commits together for a merge, I don't see any reason for the commit message to reference previous commits *at all.*

Comment: @greyfade The message would only be for a single commit. Not for all commits.  I'll clarify in the question!

Comment: @Jack: Given the new information, @Dean Harding's answer is the correct one. Just commit them separately. That's what Git was designed for.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743999/write-git-commit-message-before-git-commit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not change your "step 3" to simply "commit"? The best part of git is that it allows - even ecourages - *many small, incremental* commits to your local repository.

Comment: Right, I see what you're saying.  I guess it comes down to making smaller commits. Otherwise, I will use the --amend solution if I need to. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you ever need to use `git bisect` to track down a bug, you will be glad for small commits.

On the other hand, if the changes really are trivial, like you're running through one per minute, an oft-overlooked solution is simply to keep a GUI window open and add lines to the commit message text area.

Answer (score 2):

You can squash multiple small commits into a single one using an interactive rebase. See http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html for the description and an example.

Basically, you need to commit your changes one by one into single commits and then pack (or squash) them into a single one once you are finished. As this changes history, it should only be done in your local repository before the commits were pushed.